# Population size determination in a dataframe

Tags: categorical-data, sample-size, sample

I am running into the following problem and I was wondering if there is any easy way to solve it.

Suppose I have a Dataframe with a large number of records, let's call this number $N$.
In the dataframe I have a categorical column with let's say $4$ categories: $A, B, C, D$.

I know how many records with each category there are, so I also know the proportion of records in each category.

For practical reasons I would like to randomly select only some records from the total (each record has the same probability of being selected), let's say I select $n$ in total, but I would like to guarantee that in this selection the proportions are maintained but also that the sample is representative (with some margin of error and / or confidence level). I am not very familiar with the sampling techniques so I ask you, is there any way to know the minimum size $n$ of my sample so that I can guarantee that the proportions are maintained but also that the sample is representative? (with some confidence level and / or margin of error) I apologize if the question is very simple, but as I was saying, I am not very familiar with sampling techniques. Thank you

Comment: Unfortunately " the sample is representative" is very vague. We would need to define what does it mean, define set of rules for example, and test the drawn sample from your data comply with the rules. For proportional sample, libraries usually provide utilities for that see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59848816/balanced-row-sample-from-dataframe-with-pandas-given-categorical-target-column

Comment: This is called a "stratified (random) sample."  According to many concepts of "representative," it will be representative provided the samples of each category are (a) "representative" and (b) independent of each other.  How to partition your sampling budget of $n$ into the sample sizes for each category is another question and it requires more information about the purpose of the sampling, the analysis you intend to do, and the relative sampling costs.